# React+redux get data from child component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have creator, I mean step1 -next-> step2 -next-> ...
In my parent component I have buttons preview and next, steps content are render as child.

```
class MyCreator extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            {this.renderStep(this.props.step.id)}
         </div>
         <div>
            <button>back</button>
            <button>next</button>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

In a step  I have a component which has only two methods: getData, setData. This is a third party component (so I cannot change implementation).
When I click button `next` I want to getData from the current step. I mean call some generic method on each step child component, like leaveStep. Then leaveStep returns some data, which I will pass to redux action.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a [mcve]? It could be good to show the api you expect with the `getData` and `setData`

Comment: I try to use https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor. This component hasn't any event inform about changes. 
My solution/workaround is to dispaly editor in modal. In modal I have confirmation/save button, so I'm able to get data from editor and store data where I want to.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, the ideal solution would be lifting state up to the `Parent` component, take a look at [this part of the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). But since you don't have control of your components and it may create you some problems to sync the states. Something like this will do the trick:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        childData: null
    }

    getChildData = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            childData: data,
        }, () => { console.log(this.state); });
    }
    render() {
        return <Child setData={this.getChildData} />
    }
}

class Child extends Component {
    state = {
        data: 'this is child data'
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={() => this.props.setData(this.state.data)}>Next</button>;
    }
}
```

But remember that this creates a duplicate state, breaking the `single source of truth` and can be very messy for large applications.